# manually create the shp and properties files for geoserver pyramid file

Tags: geoserver, tiles

I am using geoserver 2.8.2 under ubuntu 14.04 with the pyramid plugins. The pyramid tiles are generated by gdal_retile.py. GeoServer will generate some new shp files and property files when I import into a new data store.

As the permission constrained of my file system, I cannot give write permission to tomcat7.

However, geoserver can import a new data store if the shp files and property files already created.

Could I create these file manually with other scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You can create these files anywhere that you do have write permission and then move them. You could use some [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) code to construct the [image pyramid](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/coverage/pyramid.html) as a user that does have write permission.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am not familiar with Java, but do figure out a way in R. Will post my codes here soon.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some R codes to manually create the properties files which is generated by geoserver (actually by GeoTools). The codes are not perfect, but work for me. I post here for other who will need them in R.

```
geoserver_retile <- function(
    input_file,
    target_dir, 
    levels = 8)
{
    # Call gdal_retile to generate tiles
    cmd <- paste0(
        'gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels ', levels
        , ' -ps 256 256 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=LZW" '
        , '-tileIndex tmp_tile_index '
        , ' -targetDir ', target_dir
        , ' ', input_file)

    system(cmd)
    dir.create(file.path(target_dir, '0'))

    # Create the zero level files
    zero_files <- list.files(target_dir, '*.tif', full.names = TRUE)
    file.rename(
        zero_files
        , file.path(target_dir, '0', basename(zero_files)))

    # Change file name of shapefile
    shp_files <- list.files(target_dir, 'tmp_tile_index*', full.names = TRUE)
    file.rename(
        shp_files
        , file.path(target_dir, '0', basename(shp_files)))


    shp_files <- list.files(
        target_dir, 'tmp_tile_index*'
        , full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)

    idx <- gsub('.*/(\\d+)/.*', '\\1', shp_files)
    shp_files_new <- unlist(lapply(seq(along = shp_files)
           , function(x) gsub('tmp_tile_index', idx[x], shp_files[x])))
    file.rename(shp_files, shp_files_new)

    # Write properities
    library(rgdal)
    options(digits = 6)

    library(raster)
    input_raster <- raster(input_files)

    writeLines(showWKT(proj4string(input_raster)), 
               file.path(target_dir,
                             paste0(basename(target_dir), '.prj')))

    input_res <- res(input_raster)

    for (i in seq(0, levels)) {
        # i <- 0
        file_name <- file.path(target_dir, i, 
                               paste0(i, '.properties'))
        prop <- sprintf('Levels=%s,%s
Heterogeneous=false
AbsolutePath=false
Name=%s
TypeName=%s
Caching=false
ExpandToRGB=false
LocationAttribute=location
SuggestedSPI=it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpi
CheckAuxiliaryMetadata=false
LevelsNum=1', input_res[1] * 2^i, input_res[2] * 2^i, i, i)
        writeLines(prop, file_name)
    }

    file_name <- file.path(target_dir,
                           paste0(basename(target_dir), '.properties'))
    input_extend <- extent(input_raster)

    prop <- sprintf('Name=%s
Levels=%s 
LevelsNum=%s
Envelope2D=%s
LevelsDirs=%s',
        basename(target_dir)
        , paste(paste0(input_res[1] * 2 ^ seq(0, levels), ',', input_res[2] * 2 ^ seq(0, levels)), collapse = ' ')
        , levels + 1
        , paste0(input_extend[1], ',', input_extend[3], ' ', input_extend[2], ',', input_extend[4])
        , paste(seq(0, levels), collapse = ' '))
    writeLines(prop, file_name)
}
```